# generator with Ruby

Tags: ruby

Im trying to create a random team generator based on the user's input of names and the number of teams evenly. Similar to this https://www.jamestease.co.uk/team-generator/

So far i've `.split` and `.shuffle` the string of input into an array of `names`, but unsure how to proceed further.

```
names = gets.split(",").shuffle

names = ["Aaron", "Nick", "Ben", "Bob", "Ted"]
```

**For Example:**
 lets say i want to have 2 teams (names do not have to be in any particular order/team):

```
team_1 = ["Nick", "Bob"]

team_2 = ["Aaron", "Ben", "Ted"]
```

Any help or tips would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

```
names = ["Aaron", "Nick", "Ben", "Bob", "Ted", 'shiva', 'hari', 'subash']

number_of_teams = 4

players_per_team = (names.count / number_of_teams.to_f).ceil

teams = []

(1..number_of_teams).each do |num|
  teams[num - 1] = names.sample(players_per_team)
  names = names - teams[num - 1]
end

> p teams
=> [["hari", "Ben"], ["Bob", "subash"], ["shiva", "Ted"], ["Nick", "Aaron"]]
```

and if

```
names = ["Aaron", "Nick", "Ben", "Bob", "Ted", 'hari', 'subash']
```

then

```
>   p teams
[["hari", "subash"], ["Bob", "Aaron"], ["Ben", "Nick"], ["Ted"]]
```

> Note: this will result random players every time you shuffle

Comment: Firstly, thanks for the input. What if we have 7 names from input and want to have 3 teams. The code above won't split it evenly as possible?

Comment: do you think its possible to sample odd number of people evenly?

Comment: well then you have to make sure that user does not input data so that such scenarios occur. Apply validations :)

Comment: Ya makes sense to add validations haha. But in a real life situation, let say a teacher wants to use this generator to help him/her divide a classroom of students evenly as possible based on a certain number of teams. He can't just omit a student or add a non-existing student.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Array#sample](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-sample) to pick random elements from the `names` array:

```
> names = ["Aaron", "Nick", "Ben", "Bob", "Ted"]
# => ["Aaron", "Nick", "Ben", "Bob", "Ted"] 
team_size = names.length/2
# => 2
> team_1 = names.sample(team_size) # pick 2 random team names
# => ["Nick", "Ben"] 
> team_2 = names - team_1 # get the remaining team names from the names array
# => ["Aaron", "Bob", "Ted"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
players = %w| Wilma Hector Alfonse Hans Luigi Bo Katz Themal Dotty Billy-Bob |

num_teams = 4

(players.shuffle + ["unfilled"]*(players.size % 4)).each_slice(num_teams).to_a.transpose
  #=> [["Katz", "Bo", "Hans"], ["Themal", "Luigi", "Billy-Bob"],
  #    ["Alfonse", "Hector", "unfilled"], ["Dotty", "Wilma", "unfilled"]]
```